# Download files from GitHub pages _site directory

Tags: git, github, synchronization, jekyll, github-pages

I am looking for a way to have my website generated by GitHub pages (jekyll) and download the generated website files in `/_site` to my web server. I hope to find a way to sync my web server with the GitHub repository as the master.

For example, I want to download all of the files from

```
https://github.com/website/website.github.io/tree/master/_site
```

What would be a neat way to do that without having to install git and cloning the whole repository on my web server?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Download the .zip and unpack perhaps ?

Comment: Why don't you generate the site locally ?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use GitHub as a build server. Why would you do that? Maybe all you need is to build the site via AppVeyor (https://www.appveyor.com) or TravisCI (https://travis-ci.org)?

Comment: I use GitHub for staging (preview) and co-working on the website. Due to the nature of the project, not all of the work can be done locally.

Comment: Since there are many possibilities (rsync, scp, ...). See [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/deployment-methods/), please.

Comment: @marcolz How would one do that? _site is not tracked.

Comment: Perhaps... You could try GitLab instead of GitHub, then deploy the website directly to your server with GitLab CI. about.gitlab.com